# What does returning true or false do to onclick?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know what happens when returning true or false to an onclick?

This is the code,

```
<button onclick="return test()">Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function test() {
        alert("hey");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Changing false to true doesn't change the function behavior.

What exactly does true or false do when returned to onclick?

Comment: Nothing in a button. If the element *does* something by itself...well, that's a different story: `<a href="/never/navigate/here" onclick="return false">can't click me!</a>`

Comment: Some browsers will submit the page if the button does not have `type="button"` so in this case it does make a difference